# How do I attach uploaded files to email notifications from Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to include uploaded files as attachments to the email notifications I receive from [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).  How do I enable this feature for my notifications?

Answer (score 1):

You can include uploaded files as attachments to both email notifications and email confirmations in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).  You can also attach PDF or Word documents generated from your form data to these emails.

These two options, along with the option to include view/edit links in these emails, is a Pro feature and requires a paid subscription to Cognito Forms.  You can see which features are included on the Pro, Team and Enterprise plans on the [pricing page](https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing).

The circled items below are the only options requiring a paid plan for email notifications.

[image]